# Laravel 8 how to use schedule:test

Tags: php, laravel, schedule

I have a question about the command `schedule:list` and `schedule:test`, On my linux server I created 3 different Jobs that simple call a command. Now using `schedule:list` I see this:

```
php artisan schedule:list
+---------+---------------+----------------------+---------------------+
| Command | Interval      | Description          | Next Due            |
+---------+---------------+----------------------+---------------------+
|         | 32 8-20 * * * | App\Jobs\importItems | 2021-06-16 11:32:00 |
|         | 0 8 * * *     | App\Jobs\deleteItems | 2021-06-17 08:00:00 |
|         | 0 22 * * *    | App\Jobs\removeItems | 2021-06-16 22:00:00 |
+---------+---------------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

This is correct, so I tried to run the Jobs manually using test:

```
php artisan schedule:test
Which command would you like to run?:
  [0]
  [1]
  [2]
 >
```

If I press enter the first one is executed without any issue but I don't understand how to launch the second or third, I tried to put `1`, `[1]`, `App\Jobs\deleteItems`, `deleteItems` but without success.

This is the Job code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Console\Command\startImport;

class importItems implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
set_time_limit(80);
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        \Log::info("Cron is working fine!");
        \Artisan::call('start:import', ['limit'=>50]);
    }
}
```

Any idea about how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance
Roy

Comment: Shouldn't you have non empty "Command" column?

Comment: I thought the same, but I don't know how to put the command name there

Comment: What about including your schedule code?

Comment: Added in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Update to >= 8.52.0

--

I believe this is a bug with Laravel because of the way it creates callback events for the schedule. It "names" the event but that sets the description. Ideally it'd also set the command for you too.

I temporarily got around this by setting the command in the Console kernel for scheduled jobs. I've not got around to filing a bug report yet. When I do i'll link to it here/update my answer.

For example in your case, you'd simply set the `command` property after creating the job.

```
    $importItems = $schedule->job(importItems::class)->dailyAt('01:00');
    $importItems->command = 'importItems';
```

Once you've set the property, pressing 0 or 1 etc when using `artisan:test` works.

### Update

This was fixed in https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/38146

and released in [v8.52.0](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/CHANGELOG-8.x.md#v8520-2021-07-27) on 2021-07-27

Comment: Really thanks, this is the correct way, now it works and I can launch using command

Comment: @Dierre this has been fixed in 8.52.0 if you upgrade Laravel you can remove the need for this fix.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the starting point is to figure out if you have actually set it up correctly. As others have stated you should have a non-empty command column. See the following picture from my server. In addition to running regular functions, I am also running queues because I can't run `supervisor` due to being on shared hosting.

[image]

I have been using the following code to schedule by `queues`

```
    $schedule->command("queue:work")->everyMinute()
               ->withoutOverlapping()->emailOutputOnFailure('cool@bananas.com');
    
 // restart the queue worker periodically to prevent memory issues
$schedule->command('queue:restart')->hourly();
```

Comment: This is because you're scheduling commands, as opposed to job classes or closures in your example. When you pass in a Job say `$schedule->job(ImportItems::class)->hourly()` the command column for that scheduled item is empty.